# How to get innertext from IE tab in Autoit

Tags: html, internet-explorer, tabs, autoit

Here is the context of my problem: I have an IE window that opens several tabs (in fact, a lot, around 50). I am navigating through the tabs (with ControlSend "^i") and wish to get the innertext of the current displayed tab. However what comes from the _IEPropertyGet($global_ie, "innertext") command is every time the innertext of the first tab (the one the IE has been created with).

My question is: how to get the innertext of the current tab?

Some constraints I have:

- I cannot doing graphical things since the IE window is going to be
  hidden
- I cannot refresh/reload the tabs/pages (with 50 tabs, it ends up with
  too much requests and being caught by the anti-DDOS bot of the
  website)
- I cannot open the tabs in different IE (too many tabs, not sure my PC
  can handle 50 IEs at once)

Additional informations:

- Tabs are created using the Navigate2 function (with the parameter
  "0x1000")
- I navigate through the tabs using the function ControlSend( ... ,
  "^$i)

I am quite new using Autoit (and any automation tools), so it is possible I didn't understand some fundamentals things.

Thanks a lot guys!

[X-POST from the Autoit forums]

Answer (score 0):

My post on the Autoit forums has been answered. And this what solved the problem. To get the active tab, I needed to use the following function:

```
Func _IEGetActiveTab()
Local $hwnd, $i, $title, $oIE

; get first IE instance
$oIE = _IEAttach ("", "instance", 1)

If @error = $_IESTATUS_Success Then
    ; get window title
    $hwnd = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd")
    $title = WinGetTitle($hwnd)

    ;strip off trailing browser text
    $i = StringInStr($title, ' - ', 0, -1)
    If $i > 0 Then
        $title = StringLeft($title, $i - 1)
    EndIf

    $oIE = _IEAttach($title, "windowtitle")
EndIf

Return $oIE
EndFunc
```

After adding some delays, and using `_IEPropertyGet($active_tab, "innertext")`, I was able to get the text of the page.